# Retrieve awesomebox.io scan page content with python-requests

Tags: python, python-requests

i'm trying to retrieve the page content from https://www.awesomebox.io/scan
But before I can do that  need to be logged in. At the moment I still get the login page content. Thats because it redirects because im not logged in.

Anybody know how to get the scan page content with python-requests?
I tried multiple requests authentication methods.

My code so far:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()

loginURL = 'http://www.awesomebox.io/login'
payload = {'username': '******','password': '******'}

session.post(loginURL, data=payload)

scanURL = "http://awesomebox.io/scan"
scanpage = session.get(scanURL)

print scanpage.content
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an account with awesomebox, so therefore don't know exactly. But nowadays a login on websites is more sophisticated and secure than a simple post of username and password.

To find out, you can do a manual login and trace the web traffic in the developer mode of the browser (e.g. **F12** for MSIE or Edge) and store it in a .har file. There you can (hopefully) see, how the Login procedure is implemented and build the same sequence in your requests session.

Sometimes there is a hidden field in the form (e.g. "lt" for login ticket) that has been populated via js by the page before. Sometimes it's even more complex, if a secret login in run via Ajax in the Background. In this case you even see nothing in the F12 view and have to dig into the js scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I noticed i forgot a hidden parameter.
I added the csrfmiddlewaretoken.